# How to invert ternary conditional expression depending on boolean value?

Tags: c#, logical-operators

I am looking for a way to invert a conditional expression based on a boolean parameter. Of course, this could be done the following way:

```
public int do(bool b)
{  
    if (b)
       return this.a ? 1 : 0;
    else 
       return this.a ? 0 : 1;
}
```

However, it would be helpful to make this whole function a one-liner. So, in terms of logical expressions, I am looking for an operation ∘  to combine `a` and `b` in a way that

a ∘ b = a

a ∘ (¬b) = ¬a

**Question:** Is there such a logical operation (or combination of operations)?

Comment: If your method had a return type it would make more sense. It looks like you want to combine `a` and `b` with `xnor` and then convert that to an `int` currently.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I fixed the sample code, thank you.

Comment: Well, it looks like if `b == this.a` then you want to return true, else false. Why not just check then `b` and `this.a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like we want xnor:

```
return (!(a ^ b)) ? 1 : 0;
```

(But we don't have a xnor operator so I've combined xor with not)

Or simplify by swapping the result subexpressions:

```
return (a ^ b) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: I feel bad for someone who will find this in production code.

Comment: @FCin - well, I'd certainly hope the method, property and variable names were more descriptive in production code. I'm also not keen on this `int` return type but that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: On `bool`, isn't `^` just the same as `!=`?

Comment: Dont worry, @FCin , this code was only posted to describe the problem; it is not production code.

Comment: @Rawling - yes. It then comes down to which way the author is thinking about the problem.

Comment: Converting Bool to Int has been an extention method of so many code, that I thought it was built in.

Answer (score 5):

A simple and easy to understand implementation I would suggest is:

```
return (b == this.a) ? 1 : 0;
```

since based on your original code you appear to want to return `1` if they are equal and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @mjwills, this looks like the most concise implementation. However, I accepted  Damien_The_Unbeliever 's answer for mentioning the logical operator I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here's the method which you need, *inverted XOR*:

```
public int do(bool b)
{  
    return b ^ this.a ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile because `bool` -> `int` isn't an allowed implicit conversion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, IMHO with the ternary operator will be the simplest possible way to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested ternary conditions:

```
public int do(bool b)
{  
   return b ? (this.a ? 1 : 0) : (this.a ? 0 : 1);
}
```

or inside-out:

```
public int do(bool b)
{  
   return this.a ? (b ? 1 : 0)
}
```

Or in your example case, it's even simpler:

```
public int do(bool b)
{  
    return a && b; // edit: won't work for !a !b, also int-cast missing...
}
```

If you find a logical expression in a truth table, it's quite easy:

[image]